# Can a server "impersonate" an user account on Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have a question, maybe a newbie question but, I would be glad if you guys help me.
Well, I wish to do all my smart contracts interactions by server-side, for instance: An user wants to create his token, so he inputs the data (name, tick, decimals ...) and send it to server that will deploy an instance of ERC20, so far so good. The transaction has a charge (gas) that my server needs to pay in order to send the transaction, but I wanna "transfer" this charge to the user who intends to create the token. I was wondering if there is any way to my server send this transaction "on behalf of someone else" and the transaction charge be payed by this address? Maybe sign the transaction on client-side and send it on server-side (I need to pay here again right)?

Comment: you could create the transaction server side and let the user sign and send it

Answer (score 0):

> but I wanna "transfer" this charge to the user who intends to create the token. I was wondering if there is any way to my server send this transaction "on behalf of someone else" and the transaction charge be payed by this address?

No. This is not how Ethereum works. You need to design the system so that the user interacts directly with the blockchain, not your server, and this is the only way to push the gas cost to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like too late to the party. But one solution would be to create a solidity token factory contract, which can deploy tokens based on user input. Here the gas fee would be paid by the user ( Since the user is going to directly interact with your contract ). One good thing about this approach is that, you can charge the user fee plus an additional amount ( depending on your business logic ) , but the flip side is that as per your original question, the user wont be interacting with your server but a smart contract on chain.

Comment: Hi, i really like it. Really thank you. I will give it a try

Comment: Let us know how it goes (y)

Comment: Did it work ? Here is a sample contract - https://gist.github.com/critesjosh/e771d52f2b1a1859ab32671650afd665 

Please mark the answer correct if it was helpful